# How to create a List<WebElement> and click on an option which is throwing java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm testing a website where the xpaths are dynamic and looking for a way to click on various links in a  list. I decided to try creating a List of the webelements at the ul tag which is static. However, when I do this I get an out of bounds exception like the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 
2, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
at automationFramework.ThirdIronTest.main(ThirdIronTest.java:40)
```

I know the li elements are more than size 1 and I implicitly wait before searching for each element so that I ensure each page loads but it still doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    // Open Chrome browser
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    // Maximize browser window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // Navigate to QA Environment to begin test
    driver.get("https://qa-safari-develop.browzine.com/libraries/14/subjects");

    // Allow search for elements to wait for page(s) to load
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //** HERE WE ARE CREATING ELEMNTS OF SUBJECT LIST
    List<WebElement> subjectElems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"subjects-list\"]"));

    // Click on the subject Biomedical and Health Sciences from the Browse Subjects Navigation
    subjectElems.get(2).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index out of bounds exception happens because you are getting a list of WebElements with size equals to one. I mean, you want to retrieve a `<LI>` element which contains the link Biomedical and Health Science. However, the piece of code `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"subjects-list\"]"))` gets the `<UL>` element with the id `subject-list`, which is unique in the page. So, the list has size one and the exception is thrown when you call `subjectElems.get(2).click()`.

Summarizing, to make it works, you should do something similar to:

```
// Navigate to QA Environment to begin test
driver.get("https://qa-safari-develop.browzine.com/libraries/14/subjects");

// Allow search for elements to wait for page(s) to load
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//** Getting the ul with the links
WebElement subjectElems = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"subjects-list\"]"));

  // looking for an element with link text = Biomedical and Health Sciences
   WebElement biomedicalAndHealthSciences = subjectElems.findElement(By.linkText("Biomedical and Health Sciences"));

System.out.println(biomedicalAndHealthSciences.getText());
// Click on the subject Biomedical and Health Sciences from the Browse Subjects Navigation
biomedicalAndHealthSciences.click();
```

If you want to iterate over all links in the `<UL>`:

```
    WebElement subjectElems = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"subjects-list\"]"));


 List<WebElement> linkList =  subjectElems.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

       for(WebElement link: linkList) {
             System.out.println(link.getText());
             link.click();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a *List* of all the available **Subjects** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for *visibility of the elements* and then click on the subject of your choice e.g. **Biomedical and Health Sciences** and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.List;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class click_list_item {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://qa-safari-develop.browzine.com/libraries/14/subjects");
          List<WebElement> myElements = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//a[@class='subjects-list-subject ember-view']/span[@class='subjects-list-subject-name']")));
          for(WebElement elem:myElements)
              if(elem.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("Biomedical and Health Sciences"))
              {
                  elem.click();
                  break;
              }
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Dana Fisher]